# Bayesian Inference & Determining the Prior

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have a dataset made up of the date (YYYYMMDD) of a specific event, with the time period spanning from 1970-2015.

I want to compare two time periods of 10 years each, and look at the yearly total number of events in both time periods. Ultimately, determine if the difference between the mean,std of time period A the mean,std of time period B events is statistically significant.

I decided to similarly group the number of events by year, for each year in the dataset, and use this as my prior distribution.

I have gone back and forth endlessly trying to figure out whether or not this prior makes sense. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question might be better suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree with the above re: migration, but can I add that it's not completely clear what prior you are discussing. Count data is most commonly modelled by the Poisson distribution, and the Poisson distribution's conjugate prior is the gamma distribution, so are you looking for help with specifying appropriate alpha and beta parameters for a gamma prior, or something else?